# Kolmogorov three series theorem, convergence

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_n$, $n\geq 0$, be i.i.d. random variables such that: $\mathbb E(X_1)=0$, and $0<\mathbb E(|X_1|^2)<\infty$. Given that $\alpha >\frac{1}{2}$, I need to show that for some $A>0$,  $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb P\left(\left|\frac{X_k}{k^{\alpha}}\right|\geq A\right)$ converges. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Apply Markov's inequality, i.e. $$\mathbb{P}(|Y| \geq m) \leq \frac{1}{m^2} \cdot \mathbb{E}(Y^2)$$

(If you don't get along with it, don't hesitate to ask!)